# android nav contorller destination not change after bottomSheetDialogFragment dismiss

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation component in my app for navigating between some fragments and one bottomSheetDialogFragment
I can navigate between my fragments until I open bottomSheetDialogFragment. after dismissing dialog, when I try to navigate this exception will throw

```
IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination xxx is unknown to this NavController
```

I wrote a listener to find out why this happen using

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener
```

And understand that destination correctly changing until dialog dismiss. when the dialog is dismissed, destination will stand for dialog, and when I click on a button to navigate another fragment error will occur